# Get Android keyboard height WITHOUT RESIZING the view?

Tags: android, keyboard

I have searched and searched and there I can't find a suitable and working answer for how to get the default keyboard height on Android when you are not resizing the view.

My activity needs to have this:
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing"

So how do I know the height of the keyboard when it is displaying?

Comment: As many sources suggest the only way to get the height of keyboard is to use ViewtreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener(). For that there should be a change in the view.

Comment: Unfortunately OnGlobalLayoutListener method does not work along with "adjustNothing".

Answer (score 2):

In fact there's no way to do this, and there's no 'default height' kinda value. One idea is that when showing keyboars at first time, measure your apps resized height value, and try compare this height with normal status value. Try save this value and use them.

Comment: Like I said in my question, I cannot resize the App/view, so I cannot calculate the height of the keyboard based on that. I can't believe Android does not provide a way to know this information.

Comment: Sorry to say this but it really is. There's no edit or window or ime method which can provide this information currently. Below link can be help you a little more

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31260468/how-much-percentage-of-device-screen-is-covered-by-default-soft-keyboard-in-andr